# Bottle framework caches my template even in debug mode

Tags: python, html, caching, server, bottle

There's a similar question on here, but the answers are over 2 years old and I can't get it to work.  If I'm missing something - please let me know.
[Bottle.py caching templates despite being in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073645/bottle-py-caching-templates-despite-being-in-debug-mode)

Whenever the browser points to 0.0.0.0:8080/16boxes, I need to prevent caching.  The Bottle docs say when in Debug mode, caching is disabled, but that isn't the case for me unfortunately.

Here is my hello.py code in question:

```
@route('/16boxes')
def send_static():
    response.set_header('Cache-control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate')
    return template (resource_path('16boxes.html'), globalVar0 = globalVar0)
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I open up terminal and run:  `python hello.py`

It doesn't cache when I run it on my Mac/Chrome - but when I use Windows and Internet Explorer - it uses a cached version.  How can I prevent this?

In my 16boxes.html, I even have the following in my :

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Comment: Does your application reload when you change files?

Comment: No, only when I clear my cache in my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your JavaScript onload event doesn't fire when the page loads as a result of browser caching, [jQuery's ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn) event was created for just this sort of issue.

Comment: When I type "app = bottle.app()" I get "NameError: name 'bottle' is not defined.

Comment: add `import bottle` before that line

Comment: It's funny because I always had "from bottle import...stuff" so I assumed it was imported but I guess not!  Adding import bottle allowed bottle.app() to work - but still when I run it, it's loading a cached version of my HTML file.

Comment: The thing is - when my HTML page loads, I have a javascript function on my body tag - <body onload="myfunction()">  I need this javascript function to fire for everything to work properly.  So it seems that when a cached version is loaded, that function never gets started.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? it will handle that for you with it's [ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/#fn) function

Comment: Yes!  Using Jquery ready instead of load was the fix!  Edit your answer and I'll accept!